# Destiny Legendary Edition not registering DLCs with PlayStation 4

Tags: ps4, destiny

I bought the Legendary Edition, as it included all 3 DLCs. However, when I attempt to start certain missions, I am told "requirements not met" and "requires House of Wolves".

When I go to my library, and select "my add-ons" under Destiny, it shows my DLCs, but it still says I need to purchase them.

Why isn't Destiny registering my Legendary Edition DLCs?

Comment: to clarify, did you download the DLCs? Installing from the disc should just give you destiny, you should be required to enter in codes for DLCs.

Comment: I haven't yet, but now that you mention it, that might work

Comment: The problem you report is destiny not registering the DLCs. Yeah. Registering the DLCs first helps.

Comment: Lol, thanks man it is working now I just had to look at the codes that came in the box and type those in.

Comment: just make sure you accept the answer, and be a bit more careful, next time. This is one of those cases where reading the included material answers the question for you. Not the type of thing we like to take, on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** If a game comes with "DLC Keys", you **must** register those keys, before you will be given access to the DLC. Furthermore, if the key has been used, it will likely not work again. This should only be an issue with pre-owned games.

You report not having entered the keys that came with your copy of Destiny, yet.

When a retail version of a game comes with DLC content, it is most common for this DLC to be provided in the form of a DLC key. The idea is that you enter the code on the related store screen, which registers the DLC to your account.

As DLC can be run directly from the hard drive, and does not require a disc, this gives the developers the security of knowing you will not simply install the DLC, and exchange the disc for something else.

In other words, the game is telling you that you have to purchase the DLCs, because you simply have not registered them yet. As far as Sony are concerned, you have not purchased the rights to play them, yet. Once you have registered the keys with the PlayStation store, Destiny will acknowledge DLC access, and you should not have any more problems.